# Is there a EIP712 pendant in rust?

Tags: smart-contract, rust

I am looking for an implementation of the EIP712 standard in rust.
Like the psp22 openbrush standard which is more or less the equivalent
to the erc20 standard.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://github.com/paritytech/EIP-712 and https://github.com/SamWilsn/eip712#rust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a crate `eip_712` ([docs.rs](https://docs.rs/eip-712/latest/eip_712/), [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/eip-712)). It hasn't been updated for quite some time though.